# Zend_Form_Element_Note not exist in Zend Framework 1.11.7, what function I can use for replace?

Tags: zend-framework

I use Zend_Form_Element_Note in Zend Framework 1.12, but  this method doesn't exist in Zend Framework 1.11.7,which similar methods can I use ?.

Answer (score -1):

For resolved this problem I used.

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('name'); 
$element->setLabel('somelabel');
```

This will show just label and remove name and value propertie by javascript

```
$("input[type=hidden]").remove();
```

Comment: Building a form and then hacking piecces out of it client-side via Javascript doesn't feel like a sensible solution.